# How to delay aiogram command?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I have inline buttons with a response to them, some people spam them, I would like to make a delay for the command.

How to implement this?

If possible, write another way to answer the user that the command can be written after a while

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(id, text='Правила ⚔️')  
@dp.callback_query_handler(id, text='Мануалы ') 
async def inline_kb_answer_callback_handler(query: types.CallbackQuery):
    answer_data = query.data
    # always answer callback queries, even if you have nothing to say
    await query.answer(f'Вы выбрали пункт {answer_data!r}')

    if answer_data == 'Помощь ':
        text = "Есть какие-то вопросы? \n \nПо вопросам внутри чата:\n \n Сотрудничество - @reimannlive  \n \nПо всем вопросам: @FollHash ☯️\nПо всем вопросам, заявкам в тиму: @t3sse ☯️\n \nВот полезные команды, для развлекухи:\n \n/cat - киски \n/dog - собачки \n/music - музычка \n/robot - бредовый видосик "
        
   
    elif answer_data == 'Правила ⚔️':
        text = """Пᴩᴀʙиᴧᴀ чᴀᴛᴀ 

=======================

Зᴀᴨᴩᴇщᴇнᴏ: 

- ᴧюбᴀя ᴋᴏʍʍᴇᴩция ʙ чᴀᴛᴇ (ᴨᴏᴋуᴨᴋᴀ/ᴨᴩᴏдᴀжᴀ)

- уᴋᴀɜыʙᴀᴛь иᴧи ᴨᴏʍᴇчᴀᴛь дᴩуᴦиᴇ ᴋᴀнᴀᴧы иᴧи бᴏᴛы

- ᴩᴇᴋᴧᴀʍᴀ иᴧи уᴨᴏʍинᴀниᴇ ᴨᴏхᴏжих ᴩᴇᴄуᴩᴄᴏʙ/ɯᴏᴨᴏʙ/нᴇйʍᴏʙ ʙ ᴧюбᴏʍ ᴋᴏнᴛᴇᴋᴄᴛᴇ

-  ᴨᴏᴨᴩᴏɯᴀйничᴇᴄᴛʙᴏ

-  ɜᴧᴏуᴨᴏᴛᴩᴇбᴧᴇниᴇ "CAPS LOCK"

-  ʙᴇᴄᴛи ᴄᴇбя нᴇᴀдᴇᴋʙᴀᴛнᴏ ʙ чᴀᴛᴇ и ᴩᴀɜʙᴏдиᴛь "ᴄᴩᴀч"

-  ᴏᴄᴋᴏᴩбᴧᴇниᴇ "мᴏдᴇᴩᴀции/ᴨᴩᴏᴇᴋᴛᴀ/ɯᴏᴨᴀ" - бᴀн ❗️

-  ᴏᴛᴨᴩᴀʙᴧяᴛь ᴄᴋᴩиʍᴇᴩы, ᴩᴀᴄчᴧᴇнᴇнᴋу, ᴄʙᴀᴄᴛиᴋу, нᴀциɜʍ, ᴋᴏнᴛᴇнᴛ 

- ᴏɸᴏᴩʍᴧяᴛь ᴩᴀɜᴧичныᴇ ᴋᴀᴩᴛы, ᴀбуɜиᴛь ᴩᴇɸᴇᴩᴀᴧьную ᴄиᴄᴛᴇʍу, ᴄᴋᴀʍ и ᴏбʍᴀн ᴨᴏᴧьɜᴏʙᴀᴛᴇᴧᴇй

- ᴨᴩᴏᴨᴀᴦᴀндᴀ ᴨᴏᴧиᴛиᴋи

- ɸᴧуд\ᴄᴨᴀʍ ᴏдинᴀᴋᴏʙыʍи ɜᴀ ᴋᴏнᴛᴇᴋᴄᴛᴏʍ ᴄᴧᴏʙᴀʍи иᴧи ᴨᴩᴇдᴧᴏжᴇнияʍи (1 ᴨᴩᴇдуᴨᴩᴇждᴇниᴇ, ᴨᴏᴄᴧᴇ - ɯᴛᴩᴀɸ) """

    elif answer_data == 'Мануалы ':
        text = "Краткий мануал о том как обрабатывать логи - https://telegra.ph/Kak-obrabatyvat-logi-05-30\nЗа привлечение новой аудитории, выдаю логи"
        
    else:
        text = f'Unexpected callback data {answer_data!r}!'
        
    await bot.send_message(ID, text)
    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

I hope you can help me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

**aiogram** has a flood avoidance (*anti flood*) example, which basically prevents users from misusing the command. remember to install (**aiohttp, aioredis and redis**) on your server.

```
import asyncio

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.redis import RedisStorage2
from aiogram.dispatcher import DEFAULT_RATE_LIMIT
from aiogram.dispatcher.handler import CancelHandler, current_handler
from aiogram.dispatcher.middlewares import BaseMiddleware
from aiogram.utils.exceptions import Throttled

TOKEN = 'BOT_TOKEN_HERE'

# In this example Redis storage is used
storage = RedisStorage2(db=5)

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


def rate_limit(limit: int, key=None):
    """
    Decorator for configuring rate limit and key in different functions.
    :param limit:
    :param key:
    :return:
    """

    def decorator(func):
        setattr(func, 'throttling_rate_limit', limit)
        if key:
            setattr(func, 'throttling_key', key)
        return func

    return decorator


class ThrottlingMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):
    """
    Simple middleware
    """

    def __init__(self, limit=DEFAULT_RATE_LIMIT, key_prefix='antiflood_'):
        self.rate_limit = limit
        self.prefix = key_prefix
        super(ThrottlingMiddleware, self).__init__()

    async def on_process_message(self, message: types.Message, data: dict):
        """
        This handler is called when dispatcher receives a message
        :param message:
        """
        # Get current handler
        handler = current_handler.get()

        # Get dispatcher from context
        dispatcher = Dispatcher.get_current()
        # If handler was configured, get rate limit and key from handler
        if handler:
            limit = getattr(handler, 'throttling_rate_limit', self.rate_limit)
            key = getattr(handler, 'throttling_key', f"{self.prefix}_{handler.__name__}")
        else:
            limit = self.rate_limit
            key = f"{self.prefix}_message"

        # Use Dispatcher.throttle method.
        try:
            await dispatcher.throttle(key, rate=limit)
        except Throttled as t:
            # Execute action
            await self.message_throttled(message, t)

            # Cancel current handler
            raise CancelHandler()

    async def message_throttled(self, message: types.Message, throttled: Throttled):
        """
        Notify user only on first exceed and notify about unlocking only on last exceed
        :param message:
        :param throttled:
        """
        handler = current_handler.get()
        dispatcher = Dispatcher.get_current()
        if handler:
            key = getattr(handler, 'throttling_key', f"{self.prefix}_{handler.__name__}")
        else:
            key = f"{self.prefix}_message"

        # Calculate how many time is left till the block ends
        delta = throttled.rate - throttled.delta

        # Prevent flooding
        if throttled.exceeded_count <= 2:
            await message.reply('Too many requests! ')

        # Sleep.
        await asyncio.sleep(delta)

        # Check lock status
        thr = await dispatcher.check_key(key)

        # If current message is not last with current key - do not send message
        if thr.exceeded_count == throttled.exceeded_count:
            await message.reply('Unlocked.')


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
@rate_limit(5, 'start')  # this is not required but you can configure throttling manager for current handler using it
async def cmd_test(message: types.Message):
    # You can use this command every 5 seconds
    await message.reply('Test passed! You can use this command every 5 seconds.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Setup middleware
    dp.middleware.setup(ThrottlingMiddleware())

    # Start long-polling
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```